# assign value from cell range based on criteria

Tags: excel

Hi Excel Experts out there.

I'm trying to figure out a way sequentially assign a value from a range value or possibly array based on single to multiple criteria.

on the table spreadsheet below,

1. I want to the assign NEW tickets to Agents chronologically.
2. Assign the Pending tickets back to agent who previously worked on (was able to do this with `=IF(C1<>"new",I1,"")`.
3. assign the ticket another agent (using range2 if the previous agent was not present
   (or if possible use the Range1 as reference if outside of its shift)

I was thinking of using ifrand or index match but I can't really figure it out.
any help with MACRO or (preferably) cell FORMULA is much appreciated.
here's the link to the data sheet screen shot

[image: DATA SHEET]

Comment: `on the table spreadsheet below` ... your data never made it into the question

Comment: thanks for looking in Tim! I added the the screenshot of the data I'm experimenting on.